# Rewriting using htaccess causes path problems

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to modify urls as follows:

```
localhost/site/samplepage.php?lang=en
```

to

```
localhost/site/fr/samplepage
```

In my .htaccess file, here's my rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/samplepage/$ samplepage.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

It works, however in the page which is displayed (sample.php), I have a path to a .css file and this path is now not found.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
```

I guess its because it is a relative path and now we seem to be a subdirectory further down (in the fr subdirectory), where there is no css subdirectory.

How do I get around this so that I find my css subdirectory after doing the rewrite ?

Comment: Assuming your `/css` dir is at the root you can just reference it *from* the root ... e.g. `href="/css/styles.css"` - that'll work no matter how many steps you are down the path.

Comment: Apart from @CD001 's suggestion, you could also use the `<base>` tag.

Comment: Hi CD001, that's perfect. It works just as you say.

Comment: hjpotter, I'm not sure how/where to use the <base> tag that you suggest.